# How to know passed previous pages in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

Current I develop Struts2 application.According to the project requirement, I would like to know previous pages names.Let me explain a little details. I have one menu then under this menu there are sub menus. See this sample

```
    Home----->Page1-------->Page2
```

My problem is when I reach Page2, I passed Page1 and Home page.I would like to know which pages I passed before reaching Page2.Please share some ideas and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wants to implement the `breadcrumb` functionality in your application. For this a plugglable breadcrumb component is available.

The [**struts2-arianna-plugin**](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-arianna-plugin/) is a simple but quite flexible plugin to render and manage a simple, path oriented, breadcrumb bar.

It allow to declaratively mark actions that you want to be rendered on a bread crumbs trail.

For [examples](http://struts2-arianna-plugin.googlecode.com/files/struts2-arianna-showcase-0.5.0.war) and [Plugin Setup](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-arianna-plugin/wiki/PluginSetup) guide are available here.